# Image Rotates 90 degrees left when resized

Tags: php

I have a resize script and it makes every image uploaded 300x300. It works fine when something from computer or mobile is uploaded. The problem is when user decides to take a picture from camera: After the resize script image rotates 90 degrees to the left and it is a problem because it should be displayed correctly without rotating. I don't know the reason here is the script:

```
    function resize_image($path, $width, $height, $update = false) {
    $size  = getimagesize($path);// [width, height, type index]
    $types = array(1 => 'gif', 2 => 'jpeg', 3 => 'png');
    if ( array_key_exists($size['2'], $types) ) {
       $load        = 'imagecreatefrom' . $types[$size['2']];
       $save        = 'image'           . $types[$size['2']];
       $image       = $load($path);
       $resized     = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
       $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($resized, 0, 0, 0, 127);
       imagesavealpha($resized, true);
       imagefill($resized, 0, 0, $transparent);
       imagecopyresampled($resized, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size['0'], $size['1']);
       imagedestroy($image);
       return $save($resized, $update ? $path : null);
    }
 }
  if(!resize_image($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 300, 300, true))
  {
    exit();
  }
```

Comment: It is because you have not considered the orientation of the image before doing the resize. For details, you may refer to this [SO_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553125/php-imagemagick-functions-rotating-phone-images-inexplicably/70555997#70555997)

Comment: @Ken Lee Thanks for the answer. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP ImageMagick functions rotating phone images inexplicably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553125/php-imagemagick-functions-rotating-phone-images-inexplicably)

Comment: @KenLee, buggyduck - if this is a duplicate question, please vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks. I just voted to close it (need 1 more to close)